# How can I prevent sublime from inserting a new line when I paste?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Why is sublime inserting a line when I paste something? This has always sort of bothered me and I would like to prevent this.

Comment: Probably because you've copied a newline character. If you click on the gutter to the left of a line to select the entire line, for example, you also select the newline.

Comment: I see whats happening now, it happens only when i do `command + c` on a line, i guess it copys over the newline character also

Comment: Yup, that's what's happening. To prevent it, once you select a line (for example, by using `⌘+L`), hold down Shift and hit the left arrow once to back up your selection by one character, removing the newline from the end.

Comment: I see, a bit hacky. wish there was a way to disable that in the setting. thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the OS X version of Sublime does not have [key bindings](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) for the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys, possibly because some Apple keyboards don't have those keys. However, if your keyboard *does* have them, adding the following to your custom key bindings (**`Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`**) will give you some added functionality that is already in the Windows and Linux versions:

```js
{ "keys": ["home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": false} },
{ "keys": ["end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} },
{ "keys": ["shift+home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": true} },
{ "keys": ["shift+end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bof", "extend": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+end"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eof", "extend": false} }
```

Now, you can place your cursor at the beginning of the line by hitting <kbd>Home</kbd>, then hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>End</kbd> to select to the end of the line, **without** selecting the newline.

If for some reason your keyboard doesn't have <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>, you can always pick different keys - the full list is available [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#bindable-keys), along with the alphanumeric keys.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found without having to do anything additional and using default Sublime behavior is to:

> Actually place the cursor anywhere on the line before which you want to add a new line

What this does is paste the content just before the line in the right spot without adding any additional lines. Understand, it takes a while to get to this behavior but it is the shortest path without having to install new plugins or add new bindings.